# Get a list of active programs in java

Tags: java, cmd, windows-10

I need to retrieve a list of currently open programs using java. The following code gives me a list of all the programs that are active including any background processes however I need only a list of active programs.

```
try {
    String line;
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"tasklist.exe");
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        }
    input.close();
} catch (Exception err) {
    err.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am not going to be aware what programs are currently open and so will not be able to find it by searching for a series of names, as I have seen some people recommend this method.

By active program I am meaning any program that is available to the user to interact with through a window. The task manager window already splits the programs(in detailed view) into apps and background processes and I would like to be able to retrieve any programs that would be sorted under the apps section.

Comment: Try the command `jps`. It is included with Java, and only displays Java processes.

Comment: Although I also need a list of applications such as Audacity.exe and Powerpoint.exe so jps  does not help.

Comment: Please define what you call *active program*. In the common definition, background processes are active.

Comment: very much agreed with @SergeBallesta, unless you define *your* understanding of *active* this is impossible to answer.

Comment: Anyway, after more reading about it, it looks like the list of the programs listed under the *Application* group in Windows task manager is hard to obtain directly. Af far as I understand it, they are processes in the console session that own a main windows, so you will have to mix the list of tasks and the list of windows. I know no shell level way, and the API one does not seem trivial... Sorry for the bad news :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this command line

```
String command="powershell -command \"get-Process cmd | format-table mainwindowtitle\"";
```

and use it here

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the windows cmd like this :

```
try {
            String process;
            // getRuntime: Returns the runtime object associated with the current Java application.
            // exec: Executes the specified string command in a separate process.
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"tasklist.exe /fo csv /nh");
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ((process = input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(process); // <-- Print all Process here line
                                                // by line
            }
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
```